# Typing accents while having united states keyboard enabled

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I can't type accents like umlauts on my keyboard, I've English(United-States) as my only keyboard language. If I for example press '" it doesn't wait for any other input and immediately types the ' instead of waiting for me typing an e where I'd like to have the accent on, I've read other users with this problem but it's always  the case they have the wrong keyboard installed, I haven't, why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do *not* have the correct keyboard *driver* installed; the English (United States) keyboard driver does not support accented letters via the so-called ‘dead key’ mechanism.

If you generally type in English, you should add the driver for the United States - International keyboard. This uses the standard US keyboard layout, but converts those keys that can serve as accent (diacritic) marks into ‘dead keys’ so that if you type (for example) <kbd>"</kbd> then <kbd>a</kbd>, you’ll get `ä`.